# How to avoid error "must be size" when changing month names to numbers?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a character column containing month names into a numerical column containing numbers (1=January, etc.).

Example 1. This works:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Month = c("January", "January", "March", "March", "April")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  mutate(Month = which(Month == month.name)) -> df2
```

Example 2. This does not work (error: "`Month` must be size 31 or 1, not 2."):

```
df <- structure(list(Month = c("August", "August", "August", "August", 
                               "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", 
                               "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", 
                               "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", 
                               "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "December", 
                               "December", "December", "December")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))

df %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  mutate(Month = which(Month == month.name)) -> df
```

The code for converting is the same in both cases. Why doesn't it work in the second example? I can't get my head around it.

Comment: It would work with `mutate(Month = which(first(Month) == month.name))`. Since you have multiple records per month group you need to be concerned with vector recycling. An even safer way to do this might be `mutate(Month = match(Month, month.name))` and there's no need for `group_by` in that case

Comment: you could prepend `mutate` with a `rowwise %>%`

Comment: You could  debug: first find out which call throws the error,  then even go deeper liek `debug(CALLNAME)` , then   `CALLNAME(input_stuff)` and walk thru to see where your data fail to meet input rules.